# Array extension for generic items - protocol not convertible to parent protocol

Tags: arrays, generics, extension-methods, swift3

The code:

```
protocol AProtocol {}

protocol ABProtocol: AProtocol {}

struct ABStruct: ABProtocol {}

struct Wrapper<T> {
    let object: T
}

extension Array where Element == Wrapper<AProtocol> {
    func merge(with otherArray: [Element]) {}
}

let wrapper1: Wrapper<ABProtocol> = Wrapper(object: ABStruct())
let wrapper2: Wrapper<ABProtocol> = Wrapper(object: ABStruct())
let wrappers1 = [wrapper1, wrapper2]
let wrappers2 = [wrapper2, wrapper1]
// Following produces compilation error:
// '[Wrapper<ABProtocol>]' is not convertible to 'Array<Wrapper<AProtocol>>'
let result = wrappers1.merge(to: wrappers2)
```

This produces compilation error:

```
'[Wrapper<ABProtocol>]' is not convertible to 'Array<Wrapper<AProtocol>>'
```

even if `ABProtocol` inherits (extends) `AProtocol`.

Is it possible to declare `Array` (or `Collection`) extension for generic elements constrained to a protocol and any sub-protocol inheriting from it?

***Gist:*** https://gist.github.com/lukaszmargielewski/48fe181264bbc468e1c3b80aec0a6516

Comment: check if you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself